# Evitar que hibernate inserte el nombre de la clase en mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Tengo una entidad persona con dos campos simples:

```
class Customer {
    @Id
    String id
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

al hacer un save simple sobre esa entidad, usando spring mongo repository:

```
repository.save(new Customer(firstName: "Sylvannas", lastName: 'Thrall'))
repository.save(new Customer(firstName: "Princess", lastName: 'Peach'))
```

me inserta en mi colección lo siguiente:

```
_id: 59b7a2c3c3b53e60dd1c00f9
_class:"com.application.mongosample.domain.entity.Customer"
firstName: "Sylvannas"
lastName: "Thrall"

_id: 59b7a2c3c3b53e60dd1c00fa
_class: "com.application.mongosample.domain.entity.Customer"
firstName: "Princess"
lastName: "Peach"
```

lo que no me gusta es que me inserta en base de datos el nombre del paquete de la clase y no veo la utilidad de esta función.

¿cómo elimino este comportamiento de hibernate?